# How can we parametrize a single test Scenario with Multiple SOAP request in KARATE framework

Tags: soap, karate

I wanted to write a scenario for testing my soap api with multiple soap requests. One thing that i could do is make use of karate CSV file feature to test that scenario with varying data coming from csv. Now since my requests have multiple records like sited below :

```
<ExternalKeys>
     <Key name="MASTERCATALOGNAME" type="string">SYSTEM</Key>
     <Key name="PRODUCTID" type="string">SYS1</Key>
</ExternalKeys>
```

It will not be possible to keep multiple *key* in csv. Can some one please suggest a alternative? In REST we did it by keeping all json requests in a array and calling it by __row or using the below way :

```
Feature: Sample feature
  Background:
    * url restBaseApi
    * header Authorization = token
      # Reading file using feature to reduce Memory
    * def dataRequest = callonce read('ReadFiles.feature')
      # gets current time in milli second and is appended Request Header to ObjectID to create unique request ID
    * def now = function(){ return java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() }
      # Read the Request Header for each Request
    * def headerRequest = read('../data/requestHeader.json')

  Scenario Outline: Individual Rule
    Given path RestEndPoint
    * def sRequest = get[0] dataRequest.gdataRequest[?(@.testReference == '<TEST_REF>')]
    * remove sRequest.testReference
    * set sRequest.RequestHeader = headerRequest
    * set sRequest.RequestHeader.ObjectId = 'SB1000' + now()
    * karate.log ('Request is :',sRequest)
    And request sRequest
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * karate.log ('Response  is :',response)
    And match response.eResponse.stage == '<STAGE>'
     *  match response.eResponse.Response.responseDetails.code == “PME200"
     *  match response.eResponse.ObjectId  == sRequest.RequestHeader.ObjectId
   

    Examples:
      | TEST_REF | STAGE       |
      | TC01          | In progress   |
      | TC02          | closed             |
```

Please suggest a alternative to this way in SOAP. How to keep multiple soap request xmls in a file? Or some other way

Comment: closed as duplicate. once you read that and if you still have questions, ask a new question and this time keep it simple and specific. also refer this set of comprehensive examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature